# Find backoffice controller

Tags: magento2, url, controllers, admin-controller

I have a javascript call to this url : `https://mysite/admin/admin/export/export/key/b7c4bdb5a1b9f5147f498741adc99/entity/catalog_product/file_format/csv`

From this url how can I find where is located the action ?

I already know the 3 part in url...but here seems to be different. Which module I should look into, which action I should search ?

If this can help this is the main dashboard url after login

`https://sysite/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/276e1bbcbff57306/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URLs come from Magento 2's router system, which can be configured per module. This means that not all the admin controllers are in one place, example:

- `https://mysite/admin/admin/export/export/key/xxx/entity/catalog_product/file_format/csv` comes from module `magento/module-import-export`
- `https://sysite/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/xxx/` comes from module `magento/module-backend`

Both of these have their frontName and area defined by their module's `etc/adminhtml/routes.xml`, like the one for the ImportExport being this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento: framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="adminhtml">
            <module name="Magento_ImportExport" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Then from there you find the Controller in the module's `Controller/Adminhtml/` directory. Example, `https://sysite/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/xxx/` is at `Controller/Adminhtml/Dashboard/Index.php` relative to the `magento/module-backend` module